# pandas_profiling on jupyter notebook doesn't show the report on github

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook

Pandas_Profiling shows the report on the jupyter notebook collectly in the local environment, but it doesn't show on the github after uploaded and show the some progress instead ?

```
import pandas_profiling
profile=pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(train0)
profile.to_notebook_iframe()

HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Summarize dataset', max=28.0, style=ProgressStyle(descrip…
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Generate report structure', max=1.0, style=ProgressStyle(…
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Render HTML', max=1.0, style=ProgressStyle(description_wi…
```

How can I show the report with pandas_profiling on github?

```
Python 3.7.7
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.1
qtconsole        : 4.7.5
ipython          : 7.18.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.6
jupyter lab      : 2.2.8
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.7
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem, have you fixed that?

Comment: @Jude1995 No. I couldn't find the solution